# Display dataobjects from different classes in one list - SilverStripe 3.4

Tags: silverstripe

I'd like to create a loopable list of dataobjects with different classes.

Something like that, but functioning

```
DataObject::get()->filter('ClassName, ['MyClass', 'MyOtherClass']);
```

Is there a way to achieve that without subclassing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csy_dot_io you can create an `ArrayList` with both object lists:

```
public function getCombinedList()
{

    $list = ArrayList::create();
    $pushToList = function($object) use (&$list)
    {
        $list->push($object);
    };

    MyClass::get()->each($pushToList);
    MyOtherClass::get()->each($pushToList);

    return $list;

}
```

If you're looking to manage multiple objects in one GridField then you could check out [gridfieldextensions](https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe-australia/gridfieldextensions), specifically the `GridFieldAddNewMultiClass` component.